# Parallelize requests on a paginated API

Tags: python, api, concurrency, pagination

I wrote the following method to get, via an API, all elements associated to my account:

```
def get_all_elements(self, status: str = None, from_date=None, to_date=None, page: int = 0, page_size: int = 100):
    url = self.api_url
    params = {"status": status, "from": from_date, "to": to_date, "page": page, "pageSize": page_size}
    data = {}

    response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, data=data, headers=self.headers)
    result = response.json()

    x_total_count = int(response.headers["X-TotalCount"])
    x_per_page = int(response.headers["X-PerPage"])
    x_page = int(response.headers["X-Page"])

    total_pages = (x_total_count // x_per_page) + (1 if (x_total_count % x_per_page) > 0 else 0)
    for i in range(x_page + 1, total_pages):
        params["page"] = i
        response = requests.get(url=url, params=params, data=data, headers=self.headers)
        result += response.json()

    return result
```

The issue is that, most of the time, there is hundreds of pages to request to gather all elements. In order to speed up the process I'd like to get your advices on ways to parallelize requests. Any best practices to share?

Bu the way, with the headers I get, is there any way to improve the calculation of `total_pages`?